# Broken Image when uploading it to MySQL Database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to store images into a path and then upload them into my database. The DB is called "store" and the table I'm using is called "images" containing 3 fields: id, name (varchar), image (longblob). The form is the following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>Upload an Image</title>
</head>
 <body>
 <form action="upload_file.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
  <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="262144000" />
  <p>File:</p>
  <input type="file" name="image" accept="image/jpeg" accept="image/jpg" accept="image/png" accept="image/gif">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit" />
 </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

The upload_file.php is:

```html
<?php 

//Connect to database
$conn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","my_password");
if(!$conn){
 die("Could not connect to MySQL");
}
if(!mysql_select_db("store")){
 die("Could not open database:".mysql_error());
}

//file properties
$file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

if(!isset($file)){
 echo "<p>Please select an image.</p>";
} else {
 //$image = mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
 $image = base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
 $image_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['image']['name']);
 $image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
 
 if($image_size == FALSE){
  echo "<p>Sorry, this is not an image.</p>"; 
 } else {
  echo "<p>File is an image. Processing...</p>";
  if(!$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO images VALUES('','$image_name','$image')")){
   echo "<p>Problem uploading image:".mysql_error()."</p>";
  } else {
   $lastid = mysql_insert_id();
   echo "<p>Success!</p>";
   echo "<img src=get.php?id=$lastid>";
  }
 }
  
}
error_reporting(-1);

?>
```

And get.php is:

```html
<?php 
//Connect to database
$conn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","my_password");
if(!$conn){
 die("Could not connect to MySQL");
}
if(!mysql_select_db("store")){
 die("Could not open database:".mysql_error());
}

$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$image = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images WHERE id=$id");
$image = mysql_fetch_array($image);
$image = $image['image'];

header('Content-type: image/jpg'); 

echo base64_decode($image);

?>
```

The images are uploaded, but are not shown. Instead, I get a broken image icon, and I don't understand why. Can someone help me??

Comment: You should use `mysql_fetch_array()` instead of `mysql_fetch_row()`. But you should really use MySQLi instead.

Comment: What happens when you comment out `header('Content-type: image/jpg');`?

Comment: `$base64_decode()` needs to be without the dollar sign. This is a function, not a variable.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php ^ => *undefined blah blah blah*

Comment: @MichielPater I used mysql_fetch_array() , removed the dollar sign from base64_decode() and commented out the header, but the problem remains.

Comment: @joasa That's good. I added an answer which may help you solve some fundamental issues. Let me know which step fails to give you the correct result and which errors you encounter. Did you enable error reporting? If not, please have a look at the comment of Fred -ii-.

Comment: Ok, I added error reporting in upload_file.php and edited the question so that you can see if I stated it correctly. I still don't get any errors when reloading the [http://localhost/cmanager/images.php], [http://localhost/cmanager/get.php] and [http://localhost/cmanager/upload_file.php], but I get a Notice in the last one saying : _Notice: Undefined index: image in C:\xampp\htdocs\cmanager\upload_file.php on line 13_ which is this line '$file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];'

Answer (score 1):

**Try to solve this problem step by step**

This process can be identified as three parts and split up quickly. The HTML form, the PHP upload and saving to database process, and the loading from database process.

1. Try echoing the image data before inserting it into the database to see if the data is actually correct.
2. Update the database and see if the data is inserted there.
3. Load the image data from the database and echo it to see if it loads it correctly.
4. Try the full script.

This is just an example checklist. But you can change this and add more steps to it.

Also, please consider updating to [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). You are using deprecated functions which could lead to security issues. Many information sources regarding this subject can be found on the web.

Comment: Thank you for your response Michiel. Since I'm newbie in php, I'd like some more explanation on how to do step 1 please!

Comment: Would you suggest MySQLi or PDO? The main difference as I see is upon the (client side) Prepared statements. I am planning to use more databases in the future; could MySQLi support them?

Comment: I haven't looked into PDO yet myself. I use MySQLi for my own projects. To answer your first question: You create 3 new variables before inserting the data into the database. `$image`, `$image_name` and `$image_size`. After creating these variables, you could echo each of them (e.g. `echo $var;`), to see the contents of the data. Alternatively you could use `var_dump()` to get more information about the variables. Then you could add `die;` after echoing to stop the script from continuing. If you have more specific questions, you could also consider creating new questions for a better overview.

Answer (score 0):

Correct the get.php code with this code

```
<?php
//Connect to database
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "tester", "");
if (!$conn) {
    die("Could not connect to MySQL");
}
if (!mysql_select_db("tester")) {
    die("Could not open database:" . mysql_error());
}

$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$rows = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images WHERE id=$id");
$image = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows);
$image = $image['image'];

header('Content-type: image/jpg');

echo base64_decode($image);
```

> You have to change the database name and user whit your own

These are the parts that i have changed:

1. `$rows = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images WHERE id=$id");
   $image = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows);`
2. `echo base64_decode($image);`

Comment: It's resolved! Oh my god, I can't thank you enough Hubber! I spent 2 days on this thing and finally it's working. Cheers